# Looking for a better way to generate key's for a dictonary, global integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want each key to be in succession of the previous key for this list. For instance, the first key should be 1 and the next will 2, then 3...n for each method call. My code works:

```
all_randomly_generated_intigers = {}

def new_ID():
  y = random.randint(0,5)
  x = 0
  while x in all_randomly_generated_integers:
    x+=1
  all_randomly_generated_integers[x] = y
```

However, the loop will run x times for each call on new_ID(). I figured I could just call x global but my method doesn't see x if I do that:

```
all_randomly_generated_intigers = {}

global x

def new_ID():
  y = random.randint(0,5)
  while x in all_randomly_generated_integers:
    x+=1
  all_randomly_generated_integers[x] = y
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: `global` needs to be declared inside the function.

Comment: @roganjosh Do I need to declare it inside and outside of the method?

Comment: No, declaring it as global as you do is pointless, it is already global. But you're not telling the function that it needs to look outside of its own scope in order to change an immutable value (you're assigning a new object back to a name). Note that you wouldn't have this issue if you were appending to a list, because that is mutable. `global` generally leads to complicated behaviour that can make difficult bugs to solve and should really be avoided if possible. One approach (not saying it's the best) might be to make a class so that you have an object that retains its state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global x needs to be declared inside the function.

Comment: Ops it is declared before i just forgot to paste in that portion of the code, I will change that.